# How to add a syscall from a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

Ok so I'm trying to add a syscall to my Linux from a kernel module.
Here's the module code.

```C
asmlinkage int my_syscall() {
    printk(KERN_INFO "AWESOME!\n");
    return 0;
}

int load() {
    unsigned long ** addr;
    unsigned long int i = START;

    printk(KERN_INFO "IN\n");

    while (i < END) {
        addr = (unsigned long **)i;
        if (addr[__NR_close] == (unsigned long *)sys_close) {
            break;
        }
        i += sizeof(void *);
    }

    if (i != END) {
        addr += __NR_vserver;
        struct page * p = virt_to_page(addr);
        unsigned long paddr = (unsigned long)page_address(p);
        set_memory_rw(paddr, 15);
        *addr = &my_syscall;
        set_memory_ro(paddr, 15);
    }

    return 0;
}

void unload() {
    printk(KERN_INFO "OUT\n");
}

module_init(load);
module_exit(unload);
```

So I'm looking for the `sys_call_table` and once I've found it, I'm trying to override a not-implemented syscall (`vserver`).
When I `insmod` the resulting `.ko`, here's what `dmesg` is saying :

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffff81801bc0
```

`0xffffffff81801bc0` is actually the address where I'm tryng to write `&my_syscall`.
I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong but I think the memory page might still be in `ro` mode when I'm tryng to write...

Answer (score 0):

What I do not understand is the following line:

```
set_memory_rw(paddr, 15);
```

What should happen here?

You cannot change the attributes of a physical address!

Maybe the following code is correct:

```
set_memory_rw(addr, 15);
```

(In this case you do not need the physical address "paddr" nor the page "p".)

Alternatively you may try to map the physical address a second time in kernel space.

You should restore the original pointer in the "unload()" function!!

Answer (score 0):

If 0xffffffff81801bc0 is the actual address you passed into set_memory_rw(), then it is definitely wrong value.   the address is supposed to be rounded up to PAGE_MASK boundary, ie, starting address of a page, which usually ends in 4 zeroes for 64-bit system.

set_memory_rw() manipulate with the U/S bit of the memory page tables.   But there is another attribute for x86/amd64 CPU:   WP bit (inside cr0).   According to Intel manual, the WP bit override the memory page table attribute, ie, enabling/disabling the WP bit will still work irregardless the memory is readonly or not.   But then WP bit is per-cpu, so synchronize your memory access carefully, so that while changing the memory content, another CPU is not reading it.   (for your unused syscall number this should be no problem).

http://vulnfactory.org/blog/2011/08/12/wp-safe-or-not/

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have missed something in implementation of system call. Just have a look at http://arvindsraj.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/adding-hello-world-system-call-to-linux/ which explains step by step procedure to implement system call and check whether you have followed all the step properly or not.

Comment: That isn't about adding a syscall *from a module*.